How do I let the result of std::transform accumulate on an array instead of rewriting it?
When I want to compute the pairwise product of two arrays, a and b and store the result in another array, c, I may use std::transform.
long int length = 10000;
double* a = new double[length];
double* b = new double[length];
double* c = new double[length];
std::transform(a, a+length, b, c, std::multiplies<double>());

However, in some situations, c already contains important data, and I want the result to accumulate on c instead of rewriting it.
I know it can be done with an extra temporary array in this way:
double* tmp = new double[length];
std::transform(a, a+length, b, tmp, std::multiplies<double>());
std::transform(c, c+length, tmp, c, std::plus<double>());

But sometimes length can be very large, so making an extra tmp array is expensive.
Is there any way to do this without tmp?

A side note: why do you use raw C arrays instead of std::vector ?

@wohlstad Raw C arrays are shown to outperform std::vector in other important parts of my program.

this is very surprisng and uncommon.

Regarding your question: performance-wise it might be better to resort to a plain old loop in this case (unless somebody comes with a way to use a standard algorithm out of the box).

If raw C arrays are outperforming std::vector substantially in "other important parts", then those other parts are probably using std::vector inefficiently (e.g. passing vectors by value [which allocates extraneous copies] versus passing raw pointers around) or not measuring fairly (e.g. doing measurements with raw arrays that don't account for allocation/reallocation/deallocation, but measurements involving std::vector do account for the allocation/reallocation/deallocation).

Use std::span as reference type for std::vector and std::array.

You can use a view. zip_transform will perform an n-ary operation on successive elements of n input ranges, as it is iterated.
auto view = std::views::zip_transform(std::multiplies{}, std::span(a, length), std::span(b, length));
std::ranges::transform(std::span(c, length), view, c, std::plus{});


You can do all you need in one call of transform with using lambda as binary_op passed to transform:
std::transform(a, a+3, b, c, [&](auto& itemOfAArray, auto& itemOfBArray)
{ 
    int cItemOffset = &itemOfAArray - a;
    return itemOfAArray*itemOfBArray + c[cItemOffset];
});

Lamba captures c array. Lambda takes also its parameters by reference, so it can compute by using pointer aritmetic index of c array a result of multiplication and accumulation is saved to.

This is rather hacky and not the intended purpose of std::transform. In particular, I'm not sure whether the passed in object is mandated to not be a copy/move of the objects in the array.
